# Cable housing end cap for BR-M375

Tags: shimano, brakes, compatibility, parts, cable-housing

I replaced the no name brake calipers on an entry-level ebike for Shimano BR-M375. The cable housing for the rear caliper was a bit too long, so I cut off a few centimeters. Then, I put a new 5 mm end cap just to realize that it would not fit into the caliper's barrel adjuster. The old end cap is a bit smaller and fits in it (and fits in the old calipers as well). There are also grooves in it like the ones that could have been made by some sort of crimp tools.

What kind of end caps should be used with the BR-M375? I am also curious about the old end cap and what has been used to crimp it.

**BR-M375 barrel adjuster**

[image]

**Old end cap (left), New standard 5 mm end cap (right)**

[image]

**Old end cap (left), New standard 5 mm end cap (right)**

[image]

Comment: As a dirty hack, I would try crimping the new ferrule more, right up near the end.   Also, make sure there is no debris in the barrel adjuster which is holding you up.

Comment: Sounds frustrating and weird. You could try an official Shimano one - if you don't have any around you could rob one from a boxed STI set.

Comment: Can you just turn the outer cable (the housing) around, so you have the original end cap at the caliper?

Comment: @Burki yes that's a good idea that I had considered. The housing is internally routed so I would have preferred no to, but it is definitely something doable if there is no faster solution.